# -force_load on cocoapods libraries

Tags: cocoapods

How can a podfile control the -force_load flag for the libraries it manages? I have a situation where a third-party library is using headers that arent available and one of the given solutions is to remove the -ObjC linker flag, but this is needed and inserted by cocoapods.

The other solution is to use the -force_load flag on each library. How is this added to cocoapods' podfile so that it is applied to each library?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your Podfile using a [`post_install`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#post_install) hook. It will look something like this:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["OTHER_LDFLAGS"] = '$(inherited) "-force_load"'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. The flags are the same as those in the Pod.target.xconfig files

Comment: Agreed, this does nothing for my project either. The "Other Linker Flags" configuration remains the same.